# Difference Between Calling an interfaced class object with the Class name vs the Interface name

Tags: java, design-patterns, interface

Please look at the following example.

```
public interface Testing {
    public void go();
}

public class TestingImplements implements Testing {
    @Override
    public void go() {

    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        Testing throughInterface = new TestingImplements();
        TestingImplements directly = new TestingImplements();
    }
}
```

My question is, 
What advantages & disadvantages do I get by using throughInterface over directly. A little explanation would be very helpful.

```
Testing throughInterface = new TestingImplements();
```

instead of,

```
TestingImplements directly = new TestingImplements();
```

Comment: That's not a strange way, that's the preferred way.

Comment: The two examples you show are the same (copy + paste failure?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's define what the two different approaches mean :

1. When you say `Testing throughInterface = new TestingImplements();`, you are programming to an interface.
2. When you say `TestingImplements directly = new TestingImplements();`, you are programming to an implementation.

The advantages of using 1) over 2)

1. **Compile time advantage** : You can change the type of object that get's instantiated without changing the reference and be rest assured that the code will compile. For instance, you could say `Testing throughInterface = new TestingImplementsTwo();` and there would be no need to change the rest of the code because you know for a fact that `TestingImplementsTwo` will contain atleast those methods that are present in `Testing`
2. **Run time advantage** : You can swap implementations at run-time through inversion of control.

Comment: buddy, can you please extend the answer to, advantages of using 2) over 1) as well so that I can get the full picture.

Comment: There is no advantage of using 2 over 1. You should always use 1.

Answer (score -1):

the purpose of interface is implementing multiple inheritance but in your case if you want to change behavior of method in another class then that will be useful.

Comment: thanks for the answer but a little elaboration would be great.